# Developing Android Web App Vs Native App

Tags: c#, android, mobile

I am new to mobile development and I have read through the Native app Vs Mobile app pro's and con's but I would like some advice on which path I should take in building my mobile application.

Basically the back end is written in .NET and the desktop application is in C# (I am building a mobile version for the desktop application). The application itself will require an internet connection and not much else (think of google search/facebook). With this in mind, should I be writing the application as a Mobile web application in C# or build a native app for android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Native Android Apps are typically written in Java. Monodroid lets you write them in C#, but I'm not sure the state of the project.

HTML5/JS apps are written using HTML5/JS/CSS and typically involve a toolkit like Phonegap.

Since you are aware of the pro's and con's, I think it's best to choose a platform where you can best utilize your skillset. Is that HTML5/JS or Java (or using C# via Monodroid).